# 50.0 cast as int outputs 49?

Tags: math, casting, int, percentage

I've got the following line of code:

```
int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * percent);
```

I'm using this in a part of a process that crops images to thumbnails while maintaining aspect ratio.

The problem is outlined as such:

`percent = 0.08680555`,

`sourceHeight = 576`,

the calculation results in `50.0`, but when assigned to `destHeight` as an `int`, it changes to `49`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can learn what a floating point number is.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html or http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: It comes to 49.9999968 on my calculator. Or 49 when cast to an int

Comment: Agree with @Rob, the product of 0.08680555 and 576 is 49.9999968.  How did you determine the result is 50.0?

Comment: @chux Visual Studio. I put a breakpoint at the calculation and apparently `sourceHeight * percent` produces a `Single`. That's why it was coming out as exactly `50.0`.

Comment: @kehrk Thanks. Suggest that VS does not provide _exact_ values, but rounded results.  In this case, a bit too rounded for our purposes.

Comment: @chux Exactly. Problem solved at this point, however. Thanks for checking it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really 50:

```
double percent = 0.08680555;
int sourceHeight = 576;

System.out.println(sourceHeight * percent);  // e.g. Java
```

```
49.9999968
```

Casting as `int` truncates the fractional part, leaving 49.

---

You can try using some sort of `round()` function:

```
double percent = 0.08680555;
int sourceHeight = 576;

System.out.println(Math.round(sourceHeight * percent));
```

```
50
```

Answer (score 0):

You should round your number to fix the problem: `int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * percent + 0.5);`

Comment: @kehrk. Not really. If you are interested in getting the nearest integer, rounding is the way to go. It's just a difference between `floor` and `round`.

Comment: Using `double x; ... int y = (int) (x + 0.5);` does not work well when `x < 0`.  `y = (int) round(x);` does not have this limitation.

Comment: True. However, when resizing an image, the numbers are pretty much guaranteed to be positive and this does save a function call.

Answer (score 0):

casting to int will truncate. Use Convert.ToInt32() instead:

```
int destHeight = Convert.ToInt32(sourceHeight * percent);
```

Answer (score 0):

[arshajii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1357341/arshajii) is correct. When casting from floating point (e.g. `double`) to integer, the decimal is normally truncated. (In Java the integer types are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`.) To get 50, you must use a rounding function. Java example:

```
double percent = 0.08680555;
int sourceHeight = 576;
int destHeight = (int) Math.round(sourceHeight * percent);
System.out.println(destHeight);

50
```